# Regular Expression Help AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash-cs4, flash-cs3

I am working on a regular expression and I need to extract two parts of an expression that is being imported through a flashvars.

```
//sample data similar to what comes in from the flashvars. Note that the spaces are not after the and symbol, they are there because the html strips it.
var sampleText:String = "height1=60& amp;height2=80& amp;height3=95& amp;height4=75& amp;"

var heightRegExp:RegExp = /height\d/g;   //separates out the variables

var matches:Array = sampleText.match(heightRegExp);
```

Now I need help isolating the values of each variable and putting them in an array...For instance, `60, 80,` etc. I know I should be able to write this regular expression, but I just can't get the exec expression right. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: are you just trying to access the properties of the flashvars string? if so, you should just use the loaderInfo.parameters object.

Comment: No, I can access the parameters individually using the regular flashvars methods. Instead, I'd like to be able to use the string to dynamically create a reusable object. Therefore, the name/value pairs passed through will differ in purpose and will need to be parsed out to different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for not answering the question with regexes directly. I would do this:

```
var keyvalues:Array = sampleText.split("& amp;");
var firstkey:String = keyvalues[0].split("=")[0];
var firstvalue:String = keyvalues[0].split("=")[1];
```

Would that help beside the fact, that it is not using RegEx?

Comment: why not just do: var value:String = this.loaderInfo.properties['key'] ? :)

Comment: i assume, that the string she mentions is a complete value within a key. that's why it says "& amp;"

Comment: The problem is that there are different types of variables coming in in the url. It is creating a dynamic table, so ultimately there will be rows and columns and headers, so I need to be able to put them in different arrays. I can't put all of the values in the same array...so I'm thinking I first need to parse out which values I want to put in which arrays. And I'll never know how many there will be. One table may have two headers and 4 rows and another may have 3 columns and one header and 5 rows...does that make sense?

Comment: yes, it does. you could probably still work through the ONE array after the splitting and build your individual array from there, but i admit, having a clever RegEx is probably the better solution. Unfortunately i cannot give it to you right out of my head :)

Answer (score 0):

Neither the =, & or the ; are special characters, so I think you can use

```
=|&amp;
```

in a split call and then the values will be in the odd indices and the height2 style names would be in the even indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`URLUtil.stringToObject()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/URLUtil.html#stringToObject%28%29)

Something like this should work:

```
var s:String = "name=Alex&age=21";
var o:Object = URLUtil.stringToObject(s, "&amp;", true);
```

However, if you're just getting the flashvars, you should pull them from the [`loaderInfo`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/es/sdkHelp/common/langref/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#parameters) of the root.

```
this.root.loaderInfo.parameters;
```